# magento category custom layout update setTemplate for specific store

Tags: php, xml, magento

Under Custom Layout Update
I am trying to use a different template based on the STORE

Here is my XML

```
<STORE_clearance>
    <reference name="category.products">
        <action method="setTemplate"><template>catalog/category/view-custom.phtml</template></action>
    </reference>
</STORE_clearance>
```

If I cut off the "STORE_" tags, it will work. But when I actually view through that store and expect the XML to fire with the store tags - it will not work.

This is all leading to the fact that I want to use the STORE_ tag to override the default static block I have set in the admin.

The reason behind this is we have a clearance store and want to display different messaging than our regular one.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think I get you right, but have you tried editing the local.xml of your main template.

If I missed something please elaborate.